# Why are the zero stretch and shrink in the definition of \z@skip explicit?

Tags: glue

Why do both *The TeXbook* and latex.ltx define `\z@skip=0pt plus0pt minus0pt`?  Wouldn't `\z@skip=0pt` or perhaps `\z@skip=0pt\relax` be shorter and yield the same?   I always thought that the stretch and shrink are zero by default.

Comment: Why down vote??

Comment: The usual problem with "why" questions is because only the original author can really answer them.  But I agree that "wouldn't this alternative yield the same" is a good question (+1).  (I'm pretty sure that without the `\relax`, you can run into really strange errors arising from "some expression plus something else" becoming "`0pt plus something else`".  But that still leaves the question of "why not just relax?")

Comment: @Teepeemm The suggested alternatives are shorter. Also, searching for “why” returns 32,416 results as of now. I could imagine that parsing and evaluating yet another macro `\relax` might hypothetically take more time than parsing and evaluating `plus0pt minus0pt`. Or, perhaps, the default interpretation of absent stretch and shrink could hypothetically be changed to nonzeros. I don't really know; hence the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In `plain.tex` we see

```
\newskip\z@skip \z@skip=0pt plus0pt minus0pt
\newbox\voidb@x % permanently void box register
```

If it had been

```
\newskip\z@skip \z@skip=0pt
\newbox\voidb@x % permanently void box register
```

then TeX would proceed to expand `\newbox` and lose time just to put back tokens. And it would need the knowledge of what the expansion of `\newbox` is anyway.

The alternative

```
\newskip\z@skip \z@skip=0pt\relax
\newbox\voidb@x % permanently void box register
```

would avoid the expansion and produce the same result, at the expense of clarity.

In `latex.ltx` the part is a straight copy from `plain.tex`.